# Update array field in a dataframe using another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | ColA | colB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | xx | [4, 7] |
| b | x | [2, 9] |
| c | xxx | [5, 0] |

An another dataframe:

| ID | ColA | colD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | x | 6 |
| d | x | 14 |
| c | xxx | 54 |

I’d like to update the first df by adding the values in `colD` from the second df, so the result should be:

| ID | ColA | colB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | xx | [4, 7] |
| b | x | [2, 9, 6] |
| c | xxx | [5, 0, 54] |

Column `ID` is the index. Do you know if there is a fast way to do that without using a loop? I used a loop but it took too much time since the df contains more than 50000 rows.

Comment: It is useful to provide your example dataframes in the text of the question instead of as images. See guidance [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) on making tables. Also, including code you have or have tried is good. Do so with backquotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["a", "b", "c"], 
                   'ColA': ["xx", "x", "xxx"], 
                   'ColB': [[4, 7], [2, 9], [5, 0]], 
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["b", "d", "c"], 
                   'ColA': ["x", "x", "xxx"], 
                   'ColB': [6, 14, 54], 
                   })

def union(d):
    vals = df1.loc[d.index][['ID', 'ColB']].values[0].tolist()
    b = df2.loc[df2['ID'].eq(vals[0])]['ColB'].values.tolist()
    return vals[1] + b


r = ( df1.groupby(['ID', 'ColA'])
         .agg({'ColB': lambda d: union(d)}) 
      ).reset_index()

print(r)
```

```
  ID ColA        ColB
0  a   xx      [4, 7]
1  b    x   [2, 9, 6]
2  c  xxx  [5, 0, 54]
```

Comment: This solution works pretty good, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to merge, and then combine the lists into a new column and drop the others.

For example:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on = 'ID')
df['combo_list'] = df[['colB','colD'].values.tolist()
df.drop(columns = ['colB', 'colD'], inplace = True)
```